# Push to an array from with in a computed property in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2, computed-properties

I am looking to push to an array from with in a computed property in Vue.js 2, Vue is being used within Laravel and I am getting the following response.

> createSelection:"(error during evaluation)"

The following code is being used:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Credits carried through: {{ credits }}</div>
    <div v-for="meal in meals">
      {{meal}}
      <input :id="meal" :name="meal" v-model.number="creditsPerMeal[meal]" type="number">
    </div>
    <div>
      Credits used: {{creditsSum}}/{{credits}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component ready.');

        console.log(JSON.parse(this.f));

    },

    props: ['f','c'],

    name: 'credits',
    data: function () {
     var meals = JSON.parse(this.f)

     var creditsPerMeal = {}
     for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
       creditsPerMeal[meals[i]] = 0
     }

     var createSelection = []


      return {
        credits: this.c,
        meals,
        creditsPerMeal
      }
    },

    computed: {
      creditsSum () {
        return Object.values(this.creditsPerMeal).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      },

      createSelection: function (){
        for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
           createSelection.push({
              food: meals[i],
              quantity: creditsPerMeal[meals[i]]
            })
          }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Computed method should return something and actually they should not do anything, just compute something and return. Your computed method has no return at all. 
First of all move your push logic to method:

```
   computed: {
      creditsSum () {
        return Object.values(this.creditsPerMeal).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      },
   },
   methods: {
      createSelection (){
          for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
              createSelection.push({
                 food: meals[i],
                 quantity: creditsPerMeal[meals[i]]
              })
          }
      }
   }
```

Also `error during evaluation` is not description of problem and not looks like Vue problem, may be you can provide more detailed error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it is a Vue error as it only shows in the Vue dev tools and not the console. I shall give your code a go.

Comment: So added that in, would just now need to call the method what would the best way to do that? Maybe watch?

Comment: Where do you need to make call of this method? I can't see call of `createSelection` identifier in question code. Btw also looks very odd that `data` function do some actions,I reccomend return only dic and do variable initializations in `created` hook. Also `createSelection ` array should be inside of data, and when you use it you shoud reffer like `this.createSelection`, and one more thing - it is noot good idea to have method (or computed method) same named as data variable.